# Changing boolean attribute within a React state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to update a boolean attribute inside a state object, and I'm having some trouble.
Here is what I'm attempting to do:

```
this.setState(
  prevState => ({
    selectedGrocery: {
      ...prevState.selectedGrocery,
      checked: !prevState.checked
    }
  }),
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.selectedGrocery);
  }
);
```

State `selectedGrocery.checked` is initialized as `false`, and when I call the above code, it changes to `true`, but the next time the code is called, it doesn't change back to `false`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `prevState.selectedGrocery.checked` in order to use the correct property.

```
this.setState(
  prevState => ({
    selectedGrocery: {
      ...prevState.selectedGrocery,
      checked: !prevState.selectedGrocery.checked
    }
  }),
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.selectedGrocery);
  }
);
```